# Can an ER diagram model have multiple correct models?

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

Can an Entity Relationship diagram model question have multiple correct answers?. (Simply, Is there only one correct model for an ER Diagram?).

Comment: there can be multiple ER diagrams

Answer (score 0):

ERD (entity relation diagram ) it's logical step Can one see relation is a ternary between 3 tables and another one see the best answer to be many to many . It's debend on requirements and your view.

Comment: ER diagrams represent conceptual models. The ER model doesn't provide the full power of even first-order logic as the relational model does. Furthermore, in both ER and RM, relations are represented by tables, not links between tables.